FAQ: What is On topic and Off topic on this site?
On this site, what questions are considered to be on-topic and what questions are instead off-topic?

This should be regarded as "obsolete".  Precisely what is on and off topic is not clear currently.

On Topic questions

Questions about the Chinese language: This includes, grammar, pronunciation, syntax, etc.
Translation: From any language to Chinese as long as: (1) you provide research effort, without it your question will be closed. (2) you provide a detailed explanation of the original expression word. From Chinese to other languages, please refer to the target language site.
Meaning of single word/hanzi: In case of a word (from bigram upwards), you can ask if you provided research effort in your question. In case of Hanzi, the same applies and you must provide also the sentence where you found the Hanzi.

Off Topic questions

Culture: This site is about the Chinese language, not its culture. Questions about culture will be closed as Off Topic.
Names: Questions about your name meaning or asking for help in choosing a name are not allowed.


Software-related questions are still an open case.

If you still have questions or doubts that have not been covered until now, then feel free to bring the matter on the Meta or in our Chat Room; either way, we'll be happy to help you.

Why do you think culture has no relation with language?

@EnricoBrasil That's not what I said. Language and culture are intertwined, but this site treats about how to speak the Chinese language and not about the Chinese culture. That's different from what you said.

Ok, how should the user deal with his culture questions since there isn't a Chinese Culture community?

It's more relevant to talk about culture than about software-related questions regarding Chinese.

@EnricoBrasil Either join the Culture Exchange proposal (for all cultures) or create a Chinese Culture proposal (there is a Japanese Culture for example). Pure software questions are off topic. Questions about terms to be used in software are still language questions.

Cool. Who has the power to create such community? I should be done ASAP since there has been a lot of closed topics due to off-topic issues.

@EnricoBrasil You can create a proposal if you want. If it has followers, and then committers it will become a new site. :D Please see the other similar proposals to have an idea on how to do it.
